# Sublime Text 3: how to show line numbers and bookmarks in distraction free mode?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

It's quite easy to show/hide tabs or minimap in distruction free mode using View menu (Alt+V) or Ctr+Shift+P. Is it possible to do the same for line numbers and bookmark arrows?

Or maybe center whole text in a fullscreen mode? It would have the same effect.

Comment: have you considered creating a keybinding to toggle the `gutter`, `line_numbers` and `draw_centered` settings? See Changing Settings with a Key Binding in the official documentation: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html

Answer (score 42):

It is not default behavior (keybinding). You can get line numbers, centering etc. only by modifying user config (Preferences -> Settings-More -> Distraction Free-User).
Add for example this:

```
{
    "gutter": true,
    "line_numbers": true
}
```

to get line numbers.

P.S. I was also looking for some shortcut for this. No luck. This is the only way I found for now.

Comment: Note to future readers: I tried `line_numbers: true` and it wasn't working. You must use `"gutter": true` as well for it to work. Thanks @Shulyk

Comment: "gutter":true no longer necessary. Used it on false and it worked. This is on Build 3126.

Answer (score 5):

Following the comment on the question by Keith Hall, you can do it by creating a custom keybinding. Open Key Bindings from the Preferences menu and add the following to your user keymap.

```json
[
    {
        "keys": [ "ctrl+k", "ctrl+l" ],
        "command": "toggle_setting",
        "args": { "setting": "line_numbers" }
    }
]
```

I chose `ctrl-k, ctrl+l` as the binding to match with the existing binding that hides the sidebar (`ctrl-k, ctrl+b`), but obviously it can be whatever you like. Search through the list of existing bindings to avoid a clash.

Answer (score 2):

for line and column number open the setting file: (Preferences -> Settings-More -> Distraction Free-User)

```
{
    "line_numbers": true,
    "gutter": true,
    "column_number": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a solution ( ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings ):

```
{
  "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
  "draw_centered": true,
  "word_wrap": true,
  "wrap_width": 80,
  "font_size": 10,
  "rulers":
  [
    80
  ]
}
```